# Windows Forms dynamic button custom action per button

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I have written a function AddItem that adds an item to a listview. I also have created a function to create dynamic buttons. But once i create a dynamic button i would like it to have the AddItem function work when the button is pressed.

I have no clue how i would solve this because im relatively new to C# and windows forms.

```
    private void AddButton(string Name, string Text, int Posx, int Posy, double Price, string ItemName)
    {
        // Create a Button object 
        Button NewButton = new Button();

        // Set Button properties
        NewButton.Height = 50;
        NewButton.Width = 120;
        NewButton.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
        NewButton.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        NewButton.Location = new Point(Posx, Posy);
        NewButton.Text = Text;
        NewButton.Name = Name;
        NewButton.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12);

        // Add a Button Click Event handler
        NewButton.Click += new EventHandler(NewButton_Click);

        //Add to form ontop of panelButtonHamburgers
        panelButtonsHamburgers.Controls.Add(NewButton);

    }

    private void NewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddItem(Price, ItemName);
    }
```

As you can see the AddButton function takes a price and itemname, once the button is clicked i would like the additem function to run with this same price and itemname.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use the `Button.Tag` property to store the informations you need. Then, in the event handler, cast `sender` to Control (or Button) and retrieve the content of the Tag (which is of type `object`, you can store anything there). I suggest you use the `decimal` type to represent a `Price` (currency).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood, you need a hanlder that uses some specific values for each dynamic button. There are few approaches you can use.

1. Use Tag property and save values in some format

   ```
   newBut.Tag = $"{Price},{ItemName}";
   ```

   and than, in handler

   ```
   //always check for null
   Button button = sender as Button;
   string data = button.Tag as string;
   //do staff with your data
   ```
2. Create Dictionary and every time you add new button add it as a key to Dictionary and that, in handler get your data (but this is one of the worst way to do it, so try to avoid it);
3. Use "Command" pattern. Make a special class for executing your operation. It should look like this

   ```
   class MyCommand
   {
           public double Price { get; set; }
           public string Name { get; set; }
           public ListView List { get; set; } //here is the list you want to add item to.
           public void Handle (object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
                   //Do your staff here
           }
   }
   ```

It is a little bit tricky but introduces good pattern you can use in future.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a tuple to the button's `Tag`.

```
private void AddButton(string Name, string Text, int Posx, int Posy, double Price, string ItemName)
{
    ...

    NewButton.Tag = (Price, ItemName);
}
```

Then you can the get that tuple's values from the `sender` in the event, which actually is the button.

```
private void NewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double price = (((double Price, string ItemName))((Button)sender).Tag).Price;
    string itemName = (((double Price, string ItemName))((Button)sender).Tag).ItemName;

    ...
}
```